# Codepush React Native Android staging- Task installReleaseStagingDebug not found in root project

Tags: android, react-native, staging, code-push, react-native-code-push

I'm trying to configure my RN android project according to [this section](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push#multi-deployment-testing) of the react-native-code-push docs

My build.gradle file has this configuration:

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
        }
        releaseStaging {
            buildConfigField "String", "CODEPUSH_KEY", CODEPUSH_KEY_STAGING
        }
        release {
            buildConfigField "String", "CODEPUSH_KEY", CODEPUSH_KEY_PRODUCTION
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

but when i run: `react-native run-android --variant releaseStaging`

I get the error: `Task 'installReleaseStagingDebug' not found in root project 'MyAppName'.`

Also tried running `react-native run-android --configuration releaseStaging`

Which gave me a slightly better error:

```
Task 'installReleaseStaging' not found in root project 'MyAppName'. Some candidates are: 'uninstallReleaseStaging'.
```

Any idea what i'm missing?
Thanks!
Uri

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have to add signingConfig to the releaseStaging.

```
    releaseStaging {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        buildConfigField "String", "CODEPUSH_KEY", CODEPUSH_KEY_STAGING
    }
```

Then you can install it to your device. I have react-native version 0.38 so I installed it with `react-native run-android --variant=releaseStaging` , but this might be different for other react-native versions. If you have a newer version of react-native, you can do `react-native run-android --configuration=releaseStaging` instead.

Answer (score -2):

The Android Gradle plugin allows you to define custom config settings for each "build type" (e.g. debug, release)

To set this up, 
Modify android/app/build.gradle in standard React Native projects

```
android {
...
buildTypes {
    debug {
        ...
        // Note: CodePush updates should not be tested in Debug mode as they are overriden by the RN packager. However, because CodePush checks for updates in all modes, we must supply a key.
        buildConfigField "String", "CODEPUSH_KEY", '""'
        ...
    }

    releaseStaging {
        ...
        buildConfigField "String", "CODEPUSH_KEY", '"<INSERT_STAGING_KEY>"'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        ... 
    }

    release {
        ...
        buildConfigField "String", "CODEPUSH_KEY", '"<INSERT_PRODUCTION_KEY>"'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        ...
    }
}
...
```

}

**Note:** CodePush updates should not be tested in Debug mode as they are overriden by the RN packager. However, because CodePush checks for updates in all modes, we must supply a key.

`buildConfigField "String", "CODEPUSH_KEY", '""'`

For latest react-native; you can build with

```
`react-native run-android --variant releaseStaging`
```

Comment: This does not answer the question and seems to be mostly just copied from the CodePush docs.